# Editing a Content editor web part leads to loss of embedded CSS & javascripts in other content editor web parts

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-editor-web-part

I'm using sharepoint 2013. We have many content editor web parts in the same page which contains CSS and javascripts in it. When i edit one web part, i can see some CSS/Javascripts are getting messed up in others and sometimes in the same web part also. Not sure what is the reason, but this issue is mostly happening in IE9 and surprisingly much lesser ratio in the firefox.

I know i can solve this by linking it to some files, but i don't want to do it. 
Do anyone face this issue and have any solution?.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Today I've got reported that one page looks a little bit different than is should be. After opening a content editor wp on the page that contains just css style definition, I discovered that all class names,id values and css property names are lost in the cewp.